# How to test for the line that separates the body and the header of the POST request?

Tags: python, http, post, http-post

I'm trying to get the parameters first and last from the body of the POST request. Essentially I have a socket server. This socket server gets the client when it connects and makes a file `client= connection.makefile("wrb")`.

```
...
b'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0\r\n'
b'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n'
b'Referer: http://localhost:8080/app-index\r\n'
b'Content-Length: 22\r\n'
b'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1\r\n'
b'first=dasda&last=dasda'
```

Now I go through the file by using readline().

```
while 1:
   line = client.readline()
   print(line)
   if("Content-Length" in line.decode("utf-8")):
      num=line.decode("utf-8")
   "if line doesnt have \n break":
      break
temp = client.read(int(num[16:]))
```

The `num` variable is the content length of the body. Now I'm trying to get a way to break the while when it reaches the body and use `read(num)` to read the contents of the body and then process them further.

I don't know where else to go with this - if there is a more efficient way of reading the raw POST data I'd love to hear it but I cannot use any modules or imports (I'd love to use the `requests` module but that's just not an option).

The issue with the code above is that when it comes to the body it never stops because it's looking for the last `\n`. I can't append it to the client because `client.write()` returns a header to the client.

I've tried a lot of things, I tried `readline()`, `read()`, `readlines()`, but the thing is the same - I need to stop reading at the start of the `body()` and I need to do that without any other modules

Comment: Parsing HTTP/1.1 messages is hard, due to the textual nature of the header block and the various ways to delimit the message. It's probably a bad idea to attempt to write a custom parser. In any case, see Section 3.3.3 of RFC 7230 (https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#rfc.section.3.3.3)

Comment: you're calling `readline()` twice in each iteration of the loop, this means you're discarding every other line!

Comment: @SamMason Yes I drafted the code really fast thank you for pointing it out. I've edited it now. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Following a similar implementation to how you collect the Content-Length, is it not possible to do the following?

```py
#Example:
#b'first=john&last=doe'

decoded_line = client.readline().decode("utf-8")
while decoded_line:
   if("first=" in decoded_line):
        first_split = decoded_line.split('first=')
        second_split = first_split[1].split('&last=')
        first_value = second_split[0]

    if("last=" in decoded_line):
        first_split = decoded_line.split('&last=')
        last_value = first_split[1][:-1]
```

In the event that the line exists:

first_value: should hold the first value (from example 'john')

last_value: should hold the last value (from example 'doe')

**UPDATE**

Due to misunderstanding the first question, I have added another possible solution below. If you require data from other headers the implementation can be expanded to handle that - however this will break if (for example) 'Content-Length' is missing.

```py
finished_parsing = False
content_length_line = ''

while not finished_parsing:
   line = client.readline().decode("utf-8")
   print(line)
   if("Content-Length" in line.decode("utf-8")):
       content_length_line = line
       finished_parsing = True

if content_length_line != '':
    content_length = content_length_line[16:]
```

Comment: great question, no it is not as you called client.readline() the body does NOT have a \n therefore you cannot use readline because the line never stops ^^.  You need to use the content length to get the number of bytes and then read the number of bites with the read(num) function. However reading the body is not the problem. The problem is stopping the readline() cycle before the body at the last \n character and then reading the body.

Comment: Ahh apologies - I misunderstood the question. Am I correct in thinking then that (given your example above) you wish to break the while loop when there is no '\n' and therefore after the 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests' line? In which case I will update my answer :D

Comment: That is correct, I wish to break it as soon as the header goes into the body and then read that body with the content length I gained in the loop. If im frank, with this assignment i would have used the requests module it's so well written and so simple to use but restrictions can be a bummer

Comment: Are you interested in the other headers? or just the Content-Length?

Comment: I'm just checking Content-Length so I can get the number to read the body nothing else. In the public tests I've seen that the headers are mixed and not fully filled - what im trying to say. One test has the content length and the content type and body. However another test has has the full header with everything that you see in my example. That's why I need while and am reading line by line and getting the info out of it.

Comment: @BurekKebab I have updated my answer with another solution (hopefully I am following now), as explained this can be expanded to collect the data for other Headers (but only if you can guarantee they will be there) otherwise I am out of ideas. Sorry